# Label day timing into morning, afternoon and evening in R

Tags: r, time, data-transform, wrangle

How can i label time of the day (Morning, Afternoon and Evening) for given timestamps?

## Initial Data

```
Id            Time_stamp
3083188c     2016-08-29 13:10:51
924d500e     2016-08-29 09:22:33
ad4dd7ff     2016-08-25 20:29:35
```

## Final data

```
 Id            Time_stamp              Time_of_day
3083188c     2016-08-29 13:10:51        Afternoon
924d500e     2016-08-29 09:22:33        Morning
ad4dd7ff     2016-08-25 20:29:35        Evening
```

Comment: Have look here https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/simtimer/versions/3.0.0. Then you can Work with <>=...

Comment: @Christoph Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can achieve this with `lubridate` and `cut`.

```
library(lubridate)

# transform into date time column (if it is not already one)
df$Time_stamp <- ymd_hms(df$Time_stamp)

# create breaks
breaks <- hour(hm("00:00", "6:00", "12:00", "18:00", "23:59"))
# labels for the breaks
labels <- c("Night", "Morning", "Afternoon", "Evening")

df$Time_of_day <- cut(x=hour(df$Time_stamp), breaks = breaks, labels = labels, include.lowest=TRUE)

df

        Id          Time_stamp Time_of_day
1 3083188c 2016-08-29 13:10:51   Afternoon
2 924d500e 2016-08-29 09:22:33     Morning
3 ad4dd7ff 2016-08-25 20:29:35     Evening
```

data:

```
df <- structure(list(Id = c("3083188c", "924d500e", "ad4dd7ff"), 
                     Time_stamp = c("2016-08-29 13:10:51", "2016-08-29 09:22:33", "2016-08-25 20:29:35")), 
                .Names = c("Id","Time_stamp"),
                class = "data.frame", 
                row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: How to create bin basis time category (i.e `12:00 AM to 05:00 AM, 05:00 AM to 12:00 PM etc`)